# LCP issue: longer than 2.5s (mobile)

Tags: seo

Checking the google search console I am seeing the LCP issue: longer than 2.5s (mobile) error.

My site zomex.com uses a single image as the LCP which is compressed:

https://www.zomex.com/libs/images/wordpress-themes2.png

I cannot for the life of me see how I could fix this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

I have tried compressing the image.

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons for your problem could be a slow server response, e.g., **[DNS of your domain has multi problems](https://intodns.com/zomex.com)**:

- Mismatched NS records
- DNS servers responded
- Multiple Nameservers
- Missing nameservers reported by your nameservers

In the element `head`, your website has the link to external stylesheets:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/libs/css/layout.min.css"  />
```

It can also delay loading. A possible solution is to set only the required styles on the element `head`.

Also, you can optimize images using the element **[fetchpriority](https://web.dev/fetch-priority/)** and the element **[preload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel/preload)**.

Your image can be compressed more, e.g., your image is 31.4 KB but I on the free online tool **[Compress Image](https://compressnow.com/)** with a choice of 60% was able to compress the image to 11.2 KB.

Read more **[Optimize LCP](https://web.dev/optimize-lcp)**